# What's the best way to secure frontend tokens?

Tags: security, frontend, token

Many articles and tutorials use .env to store environment variables in the frontend, however, in a productive application, this is an unsafe practice as the tokens are exposed in the browser. Knowing this, what would be the best way to secure these tokens, such as a backend API token?

Comment: If your application web server is the same as your API server you could use for instance [http-only cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies), which are not accessible to the code running in the browser.

Comment: when you say tokens do you mean user specific secrets? or developer/sys-admins secrets? there is NO secure way to include the later in the frontend, that is would be a design flaw, If you mean the former, cookies are safe enough.

It's important to understand what a "secret" is. for instance API Keys that are intended to be used in a frontend are not secrets, since they cannot be exploited in any way by a bad actor.

Comment: Yes, they are developer secrets, so I wanted to know how to keep these secrets, I've done a lot of research on this and I haven't found anything that helps much. One of the ways that would be useful would be a Proxy API that would act on behalf of the frontend, but I would like to know other types of solutions

Comment: Proxy API looks indeed like a reasonable solution, Just be sure that the piece of data is indeed a developer secret, API Keys intended for frontend usage are not secrets since there is no way that information could be abused by a bad actor.

Comment: For example, I have Azure AD secrets that cannot be exposed in the browser in any way, and the azure library needs those secrets, so would that be considered an unsafe library? as there are no ways to protect this information

Comment: AD secrets sound indeed like something you should only have in backend